# Python circular range with center point and radius from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.X, I have a list of numbers, with a maximum index of `2880`.
I want to choose an arbitrary index (eg `1500`) and define a "radius" around that index of say, 5. So, I generate a range of indicies: `1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1499, 1500, 1501, 1502, 1503, 1504, 1505`.

To do this, I'd use the following:

```
min = 0
max = 2880
center = 1500
radius = 5
r = range(center - radius, center + radius + 1)
>> 1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1499, 1500, 1501, 1502, 1503, 1504, 1505
```

The problem is, what if I define the center as 2878? I do not want `2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880,` **2881, 2882**...

I need `2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 0, 1, 2`

Is there a built in function in Python 3, which allows accepts a center, radius and array to do this? Something like:

```
def GetBounds(listOfIntegers, centerIndex, radius):
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension to do the job. Something like:

```
r = [ i % (max + 1) for i in range(center - radius, center + radius + 1)]
```

```
>>> max = 2880
>>> center = 2878
>>> radius = 5
>>> [ i % (max + 1) for i in range(center - radius, center + radius + 1)]
[2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: My god. A real life genuis. Thanks!

Comment: And there's me looking at `itertools.cycle` when all it needed was modulo. Nice

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a generator to do this. You can use the generator just like `range`.

```
def bounded_range(center, radius, highest):
    mod = highest + 1
    for i in range(center - radius, center + radius + 1):
        yield i % mod

lst = []
for i in bounded_range(1500, 5, 2880):
    lst.append(i)

print(lst)
print(list(bounded_range(2878, 5, 2880)))
```

**output**

```
[1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1499, 1500, 1501, 1502, 1503, 1504, 1505]
[2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 0, 1, 2]
```

---

BTW, you shouldn't use `min` or `max` as variable names because that shadows the built-in `min` and `max` functions.

Comment: Thanks, correct answer and good tip. However, AugBar got there first and with a very nice solution.

Comment: @pookie Them's the breaks. ;) If you actually need a list, you might as well use AugBar's list comp. But if you want a function that behaves more like `range` and only creates values as they're needed, then a generator is better than a list comp. Of course, if you only need a handful of indices it's not a big deal either way.